# Laravel composer require maatwebsite/excel not downloding

Tags: laravel

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- chumper/zipper v1.0.0 requires illuminate/support 5.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- chumper/zipper[v1.0.1, ..., v1.0.3] require illuminate/support ^5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires chumper/zipper ^1.0 -> satisfiable by chumper/zipper[v1.0.0, v1.0.1, v1.0.2, v1.0.3].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require maatwebsite/excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: I have posted this query. I was using laravel 6.5 and getting this error while loading maatwebsite via composer. Currently i am at finishing line of y project kindly anyone help me to figure out this asap. thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this post: [How to Import and Export SQL data to an Excel file](https://devnote.in/how-to-import-and-export-sql-data-to-an-excel-file/)